# Terraform: accessing EC2 instance with apache installed on the bowser using public IP address just keeps loading, loading and loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data

I am deploying an EC2 instance to AWS using terraform. I am using user data section of EC2 to install apache.

This is my template.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 2.70"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-1"
  access_key = "xxxxxxxxx"
  secret_key = "xxxxxxxxx"
}

resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  ami           = "ami-047bb4163c506cd98"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags = {
    Name = "My first terraform instance"
  }
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ "sg-0721b555cc402a3ad" ]
  user_data = "${file("install_apache.sh")}"
  key_name = "MyKey"
}
```

As you can see, I am running a shell script to install apache in the user_data section. This is my install_apache.sh file.

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
cd /tmp
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd24
echo "Hello from the EC2 instance." > /var/www/html/index.html
sudo -u root service httpd start
```

As you can see, I have assigned an existing security group to the instance. My security group white list the HTTP request on port 80 for inbound rules as follow.

[image]

Then I deploy the template running this command, "terraform apply".

Then I open the public IP address of the instance on the browser. It just keeps loading, loading and loading showing the blank screen. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: The AMI is for Amazon LInux 1 or 2?

Comment: It's for Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is form Amazon Linux 1. For AL2 it should be:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
cd /tmp
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
echo "Hello from the EC2 instance $(hostname -f)." > /var/www/html/index.html
systemctl start httpd
```

I added `$(hostname -f)` as enhancement.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I tried this. It still keeps loading, loading and loading.

Comment: The script is fine. There must be something else happening. Can you please double check security groups and?

Comment: The security group works as expected with other instance as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: @WaiYanHein I verified this script using my own instance. So can you ssh into it, and inspect `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` which logs UserData execution?

Comment: Let me check if there is any other issue.

Comment: I cannot SSH into the instance using Connect feature either. I am getting this error, "There was a problem setting up the instance connection". I also whitelisted port 22 for SSH too. Any idea why?

Comment: @WaiYanHein Your `aws_instance.myinstance` does not specify any `key_name`.

Comment: Hi yes, I have updated it to specify key. It just does not work.

Comment: @WaiYanHein If you can't ssh into the instance, then there are some more serious issues that just UserData. You would have to update the question or make new one with relevant security group settings, VPC settings, any changes to NACL's?  How do you attempt to use ssh?